# Как общатся с устройством на котором установленна Firmata на C++?

Tags: c++, arduino, serial

Допустим есть устройство на котором стоит Firmata, например Arduino. Как можно связятся с этим устройством на C++? Есть ли какая-то библиотека для данных целей? Например как Johnny-Five для NodeJS

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте добавил немного поясняющих ссылок и несколько подробнее описал вопрос, чтобы он стал более понятен и интересен широким массам.

Comment: Вот [пример использования Firmata в Arduino - Remote-Wiring](https://github.com/zfields/remote-wiring).